Manipulate the login box in Openxava
I want to move the login box to the center, which file should I modify signIn.jsp? And if I want to upload an image to appear in the interface I should do? classes
Thank you in advance
box login

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It's not needed to modify any JSP. Just write some CSS in your custom.css. Like this one:
#sign_in_box {
  position: relative;
  top: 40%;
}

